# What is it called when there is natural truncation selection?

Tags: evolution, natural-selection, evolutionary-game-theory, selection, artificial-selection

Truncation selection is when a breeder selects for animals that exhibit a value for a trait that is above a certain threshold.  What is it called when nature selects for a value of a trait that is above a certain threshold?  I want to say natural truncation selection, but I don't see any mention of that.  To clarify, what I mean is, what is it called when, as a result of natural selection, all perish but those with a value for a particular trait that exceeds a particular threshold.

Comment: The term that comes to my mind is directional selection, but I'm not sure that's what you're asking about?

Answer (score 1):

**Truncation selection**

The term  truncation selection has been used a lot in theory papers because it is a simple model and because it is of interest to breeders. Truncation selection is most likely more common in a breeding setting than in nature and from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncation_selection),  truncation selection is defined as specific to breeding

> In animal and plant breeding, truncation selection is a standard method in selective breeding in selecting animals to be bred for the next generation

However, as much as the definition fail to repeat `animal or plant` instead of just `animal`, IMO it fails to recognize that such notion could as well exist in nature. I would personally not be shock to read a paper talking about  truncation selection in wild populations.

**Threshold model**

If you really want to avoid talking about truncation selection, then you can eventually picture the phenotypic trait as a **liability factor** (as it is done in sex determination literature, see [Perrin and Beukeboom's book](https://www.amazon.ca/Evolution-Sex-Determination-Leo-Beukeboom/dp/0199657149/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1508726933&sr=8-1&keywords=evolution%20of%20sex%20determination)) and selection acting as a **threshold** on this factor. Note that the concept of threshold and [threshold model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threshold_model) is very common and everyone will understand what you mean.

Comment: "If you really want to avoid talking about truncation selection, then you can eventually picture the phenotypic trait as a liability factor (and it is done in sex determination literature, see Perrin and Beukeboom's book) and selection acting as a threshold on this factor." Can you expound on what you mean by this?

Comment: In the sex determination literature, sex is often considered as a threshold trait on some liability factor. For example in humans, SRY create TDF and TDF is the liability factor. If TDF is at a high enough concentration, it will be a male, otherwise a female. Similarly, you can picture fitness as a threshold trait where your continuous phenotype of interest (heigh or whatever) is the liability factor.

Comment: Would you define "liability factor" please?

Comment: I won't be able to cite you a nice neat definition, but I mainly encountered this term in the sex determination literature and it is some factor (protein concentration typically) which depending on its value will affect a phenotypic trait based on a threshold model. I am not sure the term is always used like this though. Sorry, I can't give you more info on that. If interested you might want to have a look at [this book](https://www.amazon.com/Evolution-Sex-Determination-Leo-Beukeboom/dp/0198753675/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1508803164&sr=8-1&keywords=beukeboom+perrin).